# SwiftUI Widget iOS 14 gradient issue

Tags: swift, ios14, swiftui, widgetkit

I want to create a gradient color for my widget using custom colors. And I have a problem when I only use two colors, as a result, not one of the colors is applied, but the background turns green!

```
struct WeatherWidgetMediumView: View {
    
    var gradient: LinearGradient {
        LinearGradient(
            gradient: Gradient(
                colors:
                [
                    Color(red: 96.0/255.0, green: 171.0/255.0, blue: 239.0/255.0),
                    Color(red: 163.0/255.0, green: 230.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0)
                ]),
            startPoint: .top,
            endPoint: .bottom)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Divider().background(Color.black).padding(.vertical, 16.0).opacity(0.1)
            }
        }
        .background(gradient)
    }
}
```

[image]

But If I added one more color it's looks great.

```
struct WeatherWidgetMediumView: View {
    let weather: Weather
    
    var gradient: LinearGradient {
        LinearGradient(
            gradient: Gradient(
                colors:
                [
                    Color(red: 96.0/255.0, green: 171.0/255.0, blue: 239.0/255.0),
                    Color(red: 96.0/255.0, green: 171.0/255.0, blue: 239.0/255.0),
                    Color(red: 163.0/255.0, green: 230.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0)
                ]),
            startPoint: .top,
            endPoint: .bottom)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Divider().background(Color.black).padding(.vertical, 16.0).opacity(0.1)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(gradient)
    }
}
```

[image]

UPD: Create a GitHub project with this issue

https://github.com/Maxim-Zakopaylov/widgetKitGradientIssue

Comment: Works fine here. Xcode 12.0. Don't you use some beta?

Comment: I'm using 12.0.1

Comment: @Asperi yo have blue gradient with firs two colors? My problem is I have't correct color when use only two colors :( When I used only two colors (both blue) I have green gradient! It's make me craze!

Comment: Yes, I have blue gradient with first code snapshot having two colors.

Comment: @MaximZakopaylov: The first code works well I tried with the same version 12.0.1, however a new version came out, try to update it.

Comment: @MaximZakopaylov Works fine for me as well (Xcode 12.0.1, previews & simulator). Looks like this is not code-related. You can try creating a new project or updating Xcode as suggested before.

Comment: @Paul Can you try this code on WidgetKit Extension? Because when I created new clean project on default view all worked fine. But when I added new widget extension I have this issue

Comment: @pawello2222 Can you try ^ it too?

Comment: I’ve already tested this in a Widget - works fine.

Comment: @MaximZakopaylov: It seems to work, do one thing, can you github your project so we can try it from there?

Comment: @Paul create a github project: https://github.com/Maxim-Zakopaylov/widgetKitGradientIssue

Comment: @MaximZakopaylov: preview u project -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3sxJ.png

Comment: @Paul it's make me crazy!

Comment: update version Xcode

Comment: Today I'm try it on new system with last Xcode on AppStore and I have same issue :(

Comment: am facing same issue with widget

Comment: @Nandha OMG! Thank you! Because I already thought I was going crazy.

Comment: Still seeing this in Xcode 13.0 :(

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the exact issue in my app, and I've fixed it by adding .blendMode(.darken) after the background modifier. I hope that would solve your problem too.

Comment: Warning! This doesn't work with Dark Mode if used as the background of a widget.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to use [Faisal's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67361558/7488171) finding without affecting dark mode behavior in release builds.

```
/// Work around Xcode bug where SwiftUI gradients show up as green in the Simulator
let workAroundBlendMode: BlendMode = {
    #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    return BlendMode.plusDarker
    #else
    return BlendMode.normal
    #endif
}()
```

Then use this with a `blendMode` modifier on your gradient:

```
RadialGradient(...)
    .blendMode(workAroundBlendMode)
```